# MySQL select in function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL function with a select inside, but always get a NULL return

```
CREATE FUNCTION test (i CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE select_var CHAR;
SET select_var = (SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = i);
RETURN select_var;
END$$

mysql> SELECT test('1')$$
+-----------------+
|    test('1')    |
+-----------------+
| NULL            | 
+-----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS
    -> $$
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'i' at row 1 | 
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: this might be obvious but is there a row in table with id = 1 ?

Comment: when I run the select on its own, it comes back with a result.

Comment: don't think that would cause this error.

Comment: is column "name" of type CHAR?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the expected result was, or what the table schema is, or what its contents look like.

Comment: The result is that I got the name (VARCHAR).  But you cannot do `RETURN VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to specify the size of `char` return type. for example if name can be of 20 characters then try

```
RETURNS CHAR(20)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Thought that just setting CHAR would be automatic.

Answer (score 12):

Does it works with this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION test (i CHAR)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(SIZE)
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
  DECLARE select_var VARCHAR(SIZE);
  SET select_var = (SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = i);
  RETURN select_var;
 END$$
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in your code, if you need only a result, you obtain it from a simple select an assign with the word **INTO** like this, remember, it return the last one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test (i CHAR)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(SIZE)
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
  DECLARE select_var VARCHAR(SIZE);
  SELECT name INTO select_var FROM table WHERE id = i;
  RETURN select_var;
 END$$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydatabase`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fnGetActiveEventId`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`mydbuser`@`%` FUNCTION `fnGetActiveEventId`() RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN   
    SET @eventId = (SELECT EventId FROM `Events` WHERE isActive=1 ORDER BY eventId DESC LIMIT 1);   
    
    RETURN @eventId;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a table named table? Escape that name if that is really what it is:

```
(SELECT name FROM `table` WHERE id = i);
```

or put the table name in....it seems to be missing